# What does the prefix "dihydro" in the systematic name of luminol refer to?

Tags: nomenclature

I'm doing a research project on the fascinating chemiluminescent molecule luminol, and figured it would be a good idea to start breaking down the systematic name of the chemical and linking the terms to the structure. The systematic name of luminol is 5-amino-2,3-dihydrophthalazine-1,4-dione, and I get it all apart from the "dihydro" - any help? Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

On the left is 5-amino-2,3-dihydrophthalazine-1,4-dione and on the right is the molecule which the name is based on, phthalazine. The 2,3-dihydro refers to the fact that at the 2 and 3 positions (the two nitrogens) hydrogens have been added (hydro is the prefix for hydrogen).

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I suspected this but didn't want to go ahead without checking. Also, for brownie points: is there a techincal name for the molecule that a molecule is based on - i.e. an OH group is called a functional group, so in the case of the luminol the phthalazine would be called its...? This word may not exist, just curious!

Comment: @AndrewCatherall I think they are just called base names

Comment: @AndrewCatherall Late to the party on this one, but in my experience luminol would be said to be derived from a phthalazine *core*.